# Double Summation Simplification

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

I want to simplify the double summation
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (\sum_{i=1}^k 3i)$$

I started by doing

$$ 3 \sum_{k=1}^n(\sum_{i=1}^k i)$$

which would give me the following, I think

$$ 3 \sum_{k=1}^n(\sum_{i=1}^k \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2})$$

I don't know how to continue from here, I just know the final answer is supposed to be

$$\dfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$$

Can someone give me some tips on how to continue after the second step?

Comment: Instead, since $\sum_{i=1}^k i = \frac {k(k+1)}2$, you should have $3 \sum_{k=1}^n \frac {k(k+1)}2$. There are many ways to prove that this sum (of triangular numbers) is equal to the given answer.

Answer (score 1):

(1) : $$\sum_{i=1}^k{ i } = \frac{{(k+1)k}}{2}$$
Plugging (1) into the double sum , we get :

$${3}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{{k^2+k}}{2} = {\frac{{3}}{2}}(\sum_{k=1}^nk^2 + \sum_{k=1}^nk )$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n  k^2 = {\frac{{1}}{6}}({{n}*(n+1) *(2n+1)} )$$

All what you have to do is  to replace the 2 sums by their expressions and then you will get it

Answer (score 0):

We are using the hockey-stick identity for binomials:

$\sum_{i=1}^k i = \binom{k+1}{2}$

$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{k+1}{2} = \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \binom{k}{2} = \binom{n+2}{3}$

$\binom{n+2}{3} = \frac{(n+2)!}{3! (n-1)!} =\frac{n (n+1)(n+2)}{6}$

Finally multiply by $3$ and you will get your result.